# Change array element in inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline

I need to change two array elements in this code. Just like i would do `str[0] = a` and `str[1] = b` in C. It is inline assembler in C code, linux.

```
char str[] = "9999\n"; 
int a = 1;
inb b = 1;
asm volatile (
    //replace 1st element of str with a here
    //replace 2st element of str with b here
    : "=r" (str)
    : "r" (a), "r" (b), "r" (str)
    : );
```

Comment: a is not the same tye as the elements of str. What do you want to happen? That `(char)1` gets put in the string or `'1'` gets put in the string?

Comment: Also, what is your actual question? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: I already edited question.

Comment: If someone gave that template to you I'd be curious why they left out something important like the `memory` clobber (which is necessary in this case)

Comment: No, i made that code. I am new to assembly. So I must add "memory" into clober list?

Comment: You wouldn't have to use `memory` if you changed the input and output constraint for `str` to `m` and `=m` instead of `r` and `=r`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am not sure why would we have to output str? str is not changing. Do you mean *str?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The array `str` is having its elements changed (not the pointer) which is the problem with this template's input and output constraints.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, Exactly. So as far as I understand, *str should be in clobber right? Pardon me if I am missing something.

Comment: Shouldn't the template be `: : "r" (a), "r" (str), "r" (b) : "m" (*str)` ?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya : since you are altering the contents of the array `str` you need to specify `=m` as an output constraint in this case. If you don't the optimizer can assume that the contents of the string array never changed.

Comment: Yeah, it's a school project.

Comment: Thanks for help! I think I am fine now.

Comment: Alternatively this would work `__asm__ ("movb %b2, %0\n\tmovb %b3, %1" : "=&m"(str[0]), "=m"(str[1]) : "ri"(a), "ri"(b));` or probably slightly better: `__asm__ ("movw %w1, %0" : "=m"(*str) : "r"((b & 0xff)<<8 | (a & 0xff)));`

Comment: Of course another way is to use individual `asm` statement to load each `    `__asm__ ("movb %b1, %0" : "=m"(str[0]) : "ri"(a));
    __asm__ ("movb %b1, %0" : "=m"(str[1]) : "ri"(b));`

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do `str[0] = a; std[1] = b;`

You can do

```
__asm__ ("movb %0, (%1)\n\tmovb %2, 1(%1)" : : "r" ((char)a), "r" (str), "r" ((char)b) : "m"(*str));
```

This is of course the AT&T style assembly.

Comment: he wants "ust like i would do str[0] = a and str[1] = b in C", not "str[b]=a;"

Comment: @Tommylee2k, I completely misread the question. Will fix this.

Comment: If you are going to go do it this way you will require the `memory` clobber because you have created a side effect in memory the template doesn't know about. From the compilers perspective it can assume that the contents of `str` never changed and assume what was in it before is still in it after. This can lead to subtle bugs if this code is optimized and part of a larger program.

Comment: No it isn't. This trivial question is a good reason people should not use inline assembly. The thing is that stuff like this will appear to work in a simple case with no optimizations in a small program. But with optimizations and part of a larger program this could cause some interesting and hard to track bugs.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Can you suggest the correct way? Else I will just remove the answer.

Answer (score -1):

So I tried

```
        char str[] = "9999\n"; 
        char a = '1';
        asm volatile (
           "movb %0,%1;"
           :
           : "r" (a), "m" (str[0])
           : );
```

It works nice but I need work in this program with **a** as integer as well. So can I convert types in assembly (from int to char)?